# How can I see the borders(containers lines) of the html tags?

Tags: html, css, web, responsive-design

I am not sure if I am expressing this the right way. But, what I would like to achieve is to see the limits-borders of the html tags, basically I would like the html tags to be inside lines-boxes so I would be able to understand their positioning and the effects of some CSS selectors easier.

Comment: Most browsers come with developer tools. If you're on chrome, try pressing ctrl+shift+j And go to the elements tab, if you aren't on there already.

Comment: It's F12 on Windows and CMD-ALT-i on Mac.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a style attribute:

```
<div style="border: 1px solid red;">div contents</div>
```

or something like that, but you're better off using the "Inspect Element" and related tools of your web browser (Chrome, Firefox, Safari) under Web development tools or right click on the element.

Answer (score 1):

```
box-sizing:border-box;
```

It includes border, padding and content inside a tag

`box-sizing:content-box;` (default)

```css
div {width:200px; padding:50px; background:tomato; border:25px red solid;}
```

```html
<div> text </div>
<!--total width: 200px+50px+50px+25px+25px=350px-->
```

```
box-sizing:border-box;
```

```css
div {box-sizing:border-box;
  width:200px; padding:50px; background:tomato; border:25px red solid;}
```

```html
<div> text </div>  
<!-- 200px -->
```

Answer (score 0):

The best tool for this is Firefox, with Firebug installed. Doesn't have to make any CSS-styling-tags that you don't really need, you can see how every element is positioned, with different color-codes for element, margin, padding etc. You can also see a lot of other information, what CSS is being used, what is being applied, what is being suppressed, etc. You can also edit stuff right in the browser, to see what different properties will do.

Comment: While Firebug is a great tool I don't agree it's the best any more. Have you checked Chrome Dev Tools in the past 3 years? It has long surpassed Firebug.

Comment: Nah. Just the fact that I can't throw it on another screen is annoying me no end. It is however pretty good, I admit that. Since there is no correlation between -webkit-capabilities and -moz-capabilities, you still have to test in both :)

Comment: Ofc you can completely undock Chrome Dev Tools to a new Window completely. It must have been a real long time since you last checked.

Comment: Oh? It wasn't an option last time I checked for it. Good to know.

Comment: And btw, I hate it to be undocked from the window it belongs to :)

Comment: Docking it to the window means it affects the viewport, which is rarely ideal for testing. Hence why it is positioned at another screen, so I can see it at all times, regardless of what I do with the window in question, and without it affecting anything because it's in the way. But I will have a better look at Chrome webtools, seems they have gotten their shit together. If now only Chrome could do all the other things my FF can do, then we can talk about changing :D

Comment: I'm working either on a 2560x1440 or a 4k monitor, so I rarely have space issues. For surfing I'd still always prefer FF over Chrome for privacy reasons.